# Panel not rendering on command button click in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, panel

I was playing around with primefaces components, when I stumbled upon this issue...

I have a sample page which contains the following,

```
<h:form>
  <p:panel id="p1">
  <p:commandButton value="display" actionListener="#{myTestBean.display}" update="p2">     </p:commandButton>

  </p:panel>

  <p:panel id="p2" rendered="#{myTestBean.show}">

  <p:inputText value="#{myTestBean.val1}" id="t1"></p:inputText>
  <p:inputText value="#{myTestBean.val2}" id="t2"></p:inputText>
  <p:commandButton value="click me" update="@form" action="#{myTestBean.disply}"></p:commandButton>

  </p:panel>
   </h:form>
```

My backing bean contains the following,

```
 public class Testbean implements Serializable {
    private String val1;
  private String val2;

  private boolean show;

    //getters and setters for the above...

        public void display(){

    if(show == false){
        setShow(true);
    }

}

public void disply(){
    System.out.println("I am here");
    val1 = "hi";
    val2 = "hello";
    if(show == false){
        setShow(true);
    }

}
}
```

Now, the catch here is, when I click my first button(display) the below panel(p2) gets rendered correctly. But when I click on the second button(click me) the panel gets hidden and also on click of second button it never goes to the backing bean method 'disply()'.

I have used action listener in the second button but again the same behavior. Also, I have given the update = "p2" in the second button, even that didn't yield what I wanted.

Could anyone help me out with this and let me know where and what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be incomplete or oversimplified code. The `p2` can never be updated this way. Perhaps you were actually updating one of its parent components?

Comment: @BalusC its oversimplified code.. Just took a snippet from the original and simplified to zero-in on the problem. I was able to update 'p2' in the above.. why do feel it cant be updated?

Comment: Ajax can only update components which are **always** rendered. So if a component is initially not rendered, then Ajax can't update it. It would only work if you update a parent component instead which is always rendered.

Comment: @BalusC Ok, I understand..In the above, the button in P1 updates the panel P2 first.. Only after that I am trying to render P2 again using the button in P2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bean needs to be placed in the view scope in order to remember all previous (ajax) actions on the same view.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {
    // ...
}
```

When the bean is placed in the request scope, then the `boolean show` would be reinitialized to default `false` and thus the `rendered` attribute would evaluate `false` while JSF is looking for the action method to be invoked and hence the action method would be never found and invoked.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)
- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Comment: @balusC.. Its working... I am not proficient in using the scopes.. yet to come to terms with that.. :) thanks for the additional info..

Answer (score 0):

When using `actionListener="#{myTestBean.display}"`, the `backinbean` method should be

```
public void display(**ActionEvent event**){

    if(show == false){
        setShow(true);
    }

}
```

and an ActionEvent parameter must be declared.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same challenge too. I tried to search online but all in vain. But after several trials, I came to figure out that since I was using the `commandButton` to set the value of the rendered panel, it was not possible to work out of `UIForm`, Therefore, I surrounded the `commandButton` with `UIForm` and it worked correctly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I surrounded the button as shown below

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton styleClass="toggle_btn" action="#{buttonNavBean.show()}" style=" font-family: sans-serif; color: black;" value="Sign In/Sign Up"></h:commandButton>
 </h:form>
```